# Starting out with python

Tags: python

I am just starting out with python today and I already see a few differences with other programming languages.

I can't get this to work.

I have a balance that need to be raised when deposit funtion is called but the value it keeps is the last value it is given.

```
        balance = 0

        counter = 0



    def deposit(amount):
        global balance
        balance = balance + amount
        counter += 1
        print (balance + counter)




deposit (1000)


deposit (10100)
```

Comment: Make sure you reproduce your indentation accurately when posting Python code. Otherwise you are introducing new errors into the code.

Comment: define "_I can't get this to work._" Does it not compile, does it crash, does it give you an unexpected result?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
balance = 0
counter = 0

def deposit(amount):
    global balance, counter
    balance = balance + amount
    counter += 1
    print (balance + counter)

deposit (1000)

deposit (10100)
```

Output :

```
1001
11102
```

Comment: You could add that the usage of `global` is considered bad style.